# Laravel table relationship get comment->username(id)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to show the username that's part of each comment block.
Currently I've got it to show Article + Comment and the body of the comment, but in my table I've assigned user_id to each comment. I can get it to show the user_id, but I'm unsure on how to look for the username assigned to that user_id.

view:

```
@foreach($article->comments as $comment)
        {{$comment->user->username}}
              {{$comment->body}}
@endforeach
```

Model Articles:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Articles extends Model
{
    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\comments')->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
    }
}
```

Model Comments:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class comments extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\users');
    }
}
```

Articles Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Articles;
use App\Comments;
use App\Users;


class ArticlesController extends Controller
{
    public function getAllArticles(){
        $results = Articles::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
        return view('index', ['articles' => $results]);
    }
}
```

Error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'users.comments_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users`
>   where `users`.`comments_id` = 16 and `u ▶"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used invalid relationship in `comments` class.

Use `belongsTo` method instead of `hasOne`, like below

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class comments extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\users')->withDefault([
            "username"=>null
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I echo the name then? If I try $comment->user->username it gives me error: Trying to get property 'username' of non-object.  if I simply do $comment->user it gives me no error, but no username obviously. How do I call upon the username?

Comment: That's the problem when the comment doen't have any user, I've updated my code to resolve that, check it out.

Comment: Ahh, I copied the database from my old one. Which had my old user_id's. It works now, thanks!